# label_map_util.load_labelmap Error: module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'gfile'

Tags: python, tensorflow

```
label_map = label_map_util.load_labelmap(PATH_TO_LABELS)
```

> AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call
>   last)  in 
>   ----> 1 label_map = label_map_util.load_labelmap(PATH_TO_LABELS)
>         2 categories = label_map_util.convert_label_map_to_categories(label_map,
>   max_num_classes=NUM_CLASSES, use_display_name=True)
>         3 category_index = label_map_util.create_category_index(categories)
>
> c:\ML\od\models\research\object_detection\utils\label_map_util.py in
>   load_labelmap(path)
>       136     a StringIntLabelMapProto
>       137   """
>   --> 138   with tf.gfile.GFile(path, 'r') as fid:
>       139     label_map_string = fid.read()
>       140     label_map = string_int_label_map_pb2.StringIntLabelMap()
>
> **AttributeError: module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'gfile'**

I know the resason of issue, its caused because of (**import tensorflow.compat.v1 as tf**) not compatble in 2.0.0. I solved it this issue using **import tensorflow.compat.v1 as tf** in my custom code, but the issue is coming from label_map_util which is inside model/research/object_detection/utils.

Do i have to degrade the version from 2.0.* to 1.* or there is any solution to it that i am missing.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, downgrading to version 1.* is necessary. Glfile was removed in 2.0.